# What is the benefit of using tokio instead of OS threads in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, threadpool, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

I am trying to make a multithreaded tcp communication program in rust

the idea is that there exists a listening socket on the main thread, and as connections come in the work is handled by worker threads

I previously used a ThreadPool approach I found in the Rust book, but as I understand tokio is able to 'automatically' assign work to threads from a pool

I am confused with what is the difference between OS threads and tokio tasks (mostly because you use `spawn` to create both)

here is some code

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello World!");
    let socket = SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(192, 168, 103, 7)), 2048);
    println!("socket -> {}", socket);

    // You need to use the tokio runtime to execute async functions
    let rt = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    rt.block_on(async {
        let listener = StartListen::new(socket).await.unwrap();
    });
}
```

and i have a `StartListen` defined in another file

```
// Defines the StartListen class
pub struct StartListen {
    listener: TcpListener,
}


// Implementation for StartListen class
impl StartListen {
    pub async fn new(socket: SocketAddr) -> Result<StartListen, StartListenError>{
        println!("Attempting to listen");
        let bind_result = TcpListener::bind(socket).await;
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
        match bind_result {
            Ok(listener) => {
                println!("Server is listening on {}", &socket);
                Ok(StartListen { listener })
            }
            Err(err) => Err(StartListenError::BindError(err)),
        }
    }
}
```

to add some more context, the idea is there are 2 types of messages that this socket is expecting

```
// Defines the types of messages to expect
pub enum RequestType {
    RequestWork {
        request_message: String,
        parameter: String,
        sender_timestamp: String,
    },
    CloseConnection {
        initial_timestamp: String,
        final_timestamp: String,
    },
    Invalid(String),
}
```

I am yet to add a `handle_connection` method, would I have to define the handle_connection to sit in a loop and spawn tasks?

```
    pub async fn accept_connections(&self) {
        loop {
            let (mut stream, addr) = self.listener.accept().await.unwrap();
            println!("New connection from {}", addr);

            // Spawn a new task to handle the connection
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
                loop {
                    let n = match stream.read(&mut buffer).await {
                        Ok(n) if n == 0 => return, // Connection closed
                        Ok(n) => n,
                        Err(e) => {
                            eprintln!("Error reading from socket: {}", e);
                            return;
                        }
                    };

                    // Convert the received message into a RequestType
                    let message = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..n]);
```

Comment: Tokio is a concurrency runtime, while OS threads allow parallelism. Googling these two terms might help you understand the difference between the two approaches.

Comment: It helps in the sense that I probably wouldn't be using tokio to split up a math calculation. If my tcp server needs to be able to handle 2 requests that come in at the same time why not dedicate an OS thread per request?

Comment: Because spinning up threads & destroying them comes at a largeish overhead.

Comment: Read through the documentation on [tasks](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/) it discusses the difference to an OS thread.

Comment: You should not ponder whether to use threads or tokio, but rather if what you need is parallelism or concurrency, because (for instance) tokio may use parallelism to achieve better concurrency performance. Usually, concurrency is better if your bottleneck is IO (which is the case when you are communicating over the internet), whereas if you need to do heavy computations, you'd do parallelism.

Comment: I'm still lost in how tokio is able to handle concurrent work. Are you supposed to accept connections using tokio but spread apart the work using worker threads? I just want to use the most efficient and cleanest approach to handle multiple connections, I'm new :()

Comment: @jthulhu thanks for the comments, my case is a LAN and requires computational work and database logging. Would you suggest to stick with the original OS thread approach for my case?

Comment: Since it's not clear (to me, at least) exactly what the biggest performance hit would be, I would suggest trying both and measuring the performance.

Comment: Note you're not limited to one or the other. You can do most of your work in the context of a Tokio runtime, but if you're going to do something that requires a lot of computation, you can use [`spawn_blocking`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html) to run the computation on a dedicated thread, and bring the result back into the Tokio context when it's completed. This leaves the Tokio worker threads free to handle other, shorter tasks, or I/O.

Comment: @userh897 What I would do: use `tokio` for async LAN connections and for the runtime (`#[tokio::main]`). Then use an async database crate for the database connection, and `spawn_blocking` for the computational work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are very close to understanding already. You are asking the right questions.

Let me give you a short rundown of possible server implementations:

- **Synchronous**. One thread that does everything, every send/recv operation is blocking.

  - The drawback is obvious: Only one connection can be dealt with simultaneously.
- **Multi-threaded**. One thread gets spawned per connection.

  - The drawback of the previous point is mitigated, we can now use multiple connections simultaneously
  - But: number of threads on our system depends on the user interaction
  - A large number of threads can break the system to the point where there are even DOS attacks that use exactly that mechanic to run a system out of memory. They make a lot of connection attempts to force the server to allocate a lot of threads, then just don't respond any more.
- **Async**. The idea is that you basically have a list of tasks, and one single thread jumps back and forth between them whenever it has time.

  - You can view it as a worker queue of coroutines; basically a list of functions that can be executed, but can be paused and put back into the queue until a certain even happens (like receiving data)
  - Fixes the DOS problem of multi-threading because jumping back and forth between work packets in a single thread is a **lot** more efficient than spawning a lot of threads
- **Multi-threaded async**. Basically the same as async, but with multiple worker threads.

  - requires a lot of thread safety, which is why this approach fits very well to the Rust programming language
  - The default type of async reactor for `tokio`. If you simply do `#[tokio::main]`, this is what you will get.
  - Has a fixed amount of threads (most likely identical to the number of cores on the system) and is therefore more robust against system overload
  - Can process a **lot** of concurrent connections efficiently.

There are a lot of subtleties to be considered, though. I strongly recommend reading the [tokio tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial), it explains many of those concepts. After that, I recommend reading the [async book](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book).

For example, some important subtleties:

- Do **not** block a task using std's synchronization primitives, under any circumstance. Blocking a task will block **everything**, because async scheduling is **non-preemptive**, meaning, the scheduler cannot unschedule a task. It can only switch tasks at `.await` points, so whenever you are waiting for something, make sure it's inside of an `.await` point. (exception: short-lived `std::sync::Mutex`, see [here](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/shared-state#on-using-stdsyncmutex))
- Don't use async tasks for heavy computation. While it technically isn't blocking, a heavy computation introduces a long time between two `.await` points. Instead, off-load it to a real thread using [`spawn_blocking`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html), which introduces an `.await` point to the worker and performs the actual computation on a different threadpool.

Comment: Thank you for providing the tutorial links!